# Facebook GraphApi don't return Reels

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Last year Meta made possible to retrieve Reels' data and metrics: this is totally true on Instragam, meanwhile for Facebook API I have some issues.

The problem is that Reels posts aren't listed when I query my/my customers feed (`https://graph.facebook.com/user-id/posts?`) and I can see the Reel object only if I call the getPost API (`https://graph.facebook.com/user-id_post-id?fields=message,permalink_url,created_time,id,full_picture`) setting post-id with the ID I find in the web url from the browser's bar. This happens both via my NodeJS app and PostMan.

Since our process is automated, this workaround is tedious and slows down the analysis and internal workflow.
Is there a solution? Looking at the docs it seems they take for granted Reels should be included in every endpoint: am I missing something?

Thank you, any tip will be appreciated!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#limitations says, _"Reels: To get a list of Reels published to your Page, use the Page VideoReels edge."_ The latter is a link, although that currently leads to a 404. But the endpoint `video_reels` appears to exist nonetheless, in a current API version.

Comment: @CBroe that's amazing! This means they're about to release the endpoint and its doc. I did a test calling the endpoint and it returns a limited set of informations, but it's still an achievement. Thank you so much for the info!

Comment: How can I get the reel by its id?